# Send array via Ajax and bind to List<string> on MVC 4

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

**AJAX:**

```
function systemsChanged(elem)
{
    var items = [];
    for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
        if (elem[i].selected) {
            items.push(elem[i].value);
        }

    var post = { ids: items };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        traditional: true,
        url: "@Url.Action("LoadApplicationConfigs", "Application")",
        content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(post),
        success: function (d) {
            alert(d.message);
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("não rolo");
        }
    });
}
```

**C# MVC 4:**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult LoadApplicationConfigs(IList<string> ids)
{
    object data = new
    {
        message = "aha!"
    };

    return new JsonResult() { Data = data };
}
```

It enters the post method but `ids` is set to `null`. I also tried changing `ids` to `string[]`, not successfully. The return to ajax is fine: it shows the "aha!" alert. I just cant seem to be providing the accurate format to the mvc binder. Any thoughts?

Comment: try simplifying it to JSON.stringify(items)

Comment: JSON.stringify(items) didnt work

Comment: Yeah as Matt says, the method is just expecting an array of strings, to get it to accept what you ware sending you would have to create a wrapper class/struct with a property called "ids", which seems pointless.

Comment: @mrsimon, i'm not sure if it will make a difference but I would make your param `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: @BenRobinson `IEnumerable<string>` didnt work either

Comment: @mrsimon Are you certain that `elem[i].value` is always a string?

Comment: Thanks @BenRobinson but JimSkerritt got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your ajax call to this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    traditional: true,
    url: "@Url.Action("LoadApplicationConfigs", "Application")",
    content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: post,
    success: function(d) {
        alert(d.message);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("não rolo");
    }
});
```

This will work with or without the `traditional` option.

Comment: It worked and Ill mark it as answer but first explain the `post.ids` part. How come `post` has an attribute called `ids` ? would I have to change it if I changed the parameter in the method?

Comment: The object that you set for the `data` field has to have field names that exactly match your parameter names in your action method. Because `ids` is expected to be `IList<string>`, settings `ids` to the entire `post` object would not work, the model binder would choke on this. In your original code, your ids were being set on a field called `ids` on your `post` object, and that's the data that you wanted to send to the server.

Comment: On further testing, you could also just set `data` equal to your `post` object since the field name matches your action method parameter name. Whoops :) I updated the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: damn! how did I not try that before. I was settled on using the JSON.stringify method. thats much better thanks man!