# Ajax sending Null to .net core MVC controller and unsure why

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I am very new to Ajax and for me it's something I can't get my head around (well jQuery in general to be honest).

I am trying to pass an object containing two string arrays, one of search parameters, another of search values.

The issue, is that when i press the submit button, the Ajax call hits the MVC controller but the Model in the Controller returns Null in both arrays.

The Ajax call:

```
    function onActivation() {
    var send = { queryParameters: queryParameters, queryValues: queryValues };
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "SearchResults")',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8;",
        data: JSON.stringify({ advancedSearch: send }),
        success: function (response) {
            response ? alert("It worked!") : alert("It didn't work.");
        }
    });
}
```

The Model:

```
public class AdvancedSearch
    {
        public string[] queryParameters { get; set; }
        public string[] queryValues { get; set; }
    }
```

The first line of the controller where things go wrong:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(AdvancedSearch advancedSearch)
```

Comment: Use just `data: JSON.stringify(send),`. You may also be able to use just `data: send,` depending on how your ModelBinder is configured

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that doesn't seem to have worked, I have changed it to your first suggestion but still returning null.

Comment: If it's *returning* null then it's a problem with your C# logic. Your question states that it's *sending* null, though...?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry i'm using the wrong terminology i think, i'm still learning my way. It is on the first line of the controller when it is hit that I check the value of advancedSearch. When looking at both arrays within it, they are both Null.

Comment: Ok. Have you checked the value of `send` using `console.log()` before you make the request to ensure it's been populated correctly?

Comment: Yep, here's the result:
queryParameters: Array [ "FirstName" ]
​
queryValues: Array [ "Charles" ]

Comment: Try if adding `[FromBody]` helps, like this: `Index([FromBody] AdvancedSearch advancedSearch)`

Comment: @PeterB it works!!! Thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you need to submit the Ajax with just `data: send`. For the model data binding to happen you can try to add another parameter in Ajax which is `traditional: true` as suggested in 
[Send array via Ajax and bind to List<string> on MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789727/send-array-via-ajax-and-bind-to-liststring-on-mvc-4)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion :) PeterB's suggestion worked for me.